# How to passes data from ViewController to UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am try to send data from ViewController to UITabBarController  ->  UINavigationController -> ViewController and try lots of way but fail to Passes data. After click in button i have asynchronous task and then need to load UITabBarController-ViewController with some data. I already almost try all example but fail to find working code.

[image]

```
     func AftergettingAsynchronousData(forUserID userID: String?) {

            guard let tabBarController = tabBarController else { return }
            let navController = tabBarController.viewControllers?[0] as! UINavigationController
            let exploreViewController = navController.topViewController as! ExploreViewController
            exploreViewController.userID = userID

        }
```

receiving data

```
  class ExploreViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


        public var userID: String?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
             super.viewDidLoad()
         print("userID  \(String(describing: userID))");
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you be little  more clear. as I understand you want to pass the data between 2 VC Right it depends kind of your data as we have so many option to pass the data. please post some code where you performs the action.

Comment: I just want to passes String type data, but let me edit my code

Comment: I edit my code please check.  mention that I need to passes data after asynchronous  task completed. and when asynchronous  task completed and i call AftergettingAsynchronousData method

Comment: can you please tell us what data you try to pass and what data fails during passing to another `ViewController`.

Comment: Ohh sorry I am getting error like this .. Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) ViewController not changes, I just send a string UserId="123101"

Comment: when i use let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        
        let nextViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Explore") as! ExploreViewController
        nextViewController.userID = userID
        self.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true). I get error

Comment: I get this error  "Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10e26fa20) to 'SplashMusic.ExploreViewController'"

Comment: you can use `prepareForSegue` method to pass data

Comment: When i use prepareForSegue,  ExploreViewController loaded but I have a Asynchronous task before getting that data page loaded and that Asynchronous task data nil

Answer (score 0):

Try changing navController.topViewController to navController.rootViewController

Comment: Value of type 'UINavigationController' has no member 'rootViewController'